# How can I overload the addition operator to work with linked lists?

Tags: c++, linked-list, shared-ptr

I am building a program that works with linked lists in order to store a polynomial. Basically, the user enters in the name of a .txt file, that file is opened, read, and the coefficients and exponents are inserted into the data fields of each node. The nodes represent the terms in the polynomial. I have two classes, the outer class is Polynomial and the nested class is Term. I have begun to write the definition to overload the addition operator. My basic idea on how to do this so far is to make a for loop nested in another for loop. I just don't know how to store my results in the new Polynomial object I created...

```
#include "polynomial.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>


double Polynomial::TOL = .000000000001;   // tolerance for floating pt. equality


Polynomial::Term::Term( double c, int e, shared_ptr<Term> n )
   {

   coeff = c; exponent = e; next = n;

   }

Polynomial::Polynomial()
   {
   head = nullptr;
   }


 Polynomial::Polynomial( string & str )
   {
   stringstream ss( str );  // stringstream lets us extract items separated by
                            // whitespace simply by using the >> operator
   double coefficient;      // to hold the coefficient
   int exp;                 // to hold the exponent
   head = nullptr;          // initialize head to null

   // read in coefficient-exponent pairs and add each term to the list
   // ----------------------------------------------------------------
   while (ss >> coefficient >> exp)
      if (coefficient != 0)   // don't make a 0 term
         head = shared_ptr<Term>(new Term( coefficient, exp, head ));
   }
```

overloaded addition function so far

```
Polynomial Polynomial::operator+( const Polynomial &other ) const
   {
       shared_ptr<Polynomial> result = shared_ptr<Polynomial>(new Polynomial()); // where you are going to store your results
       shared_ptr<Polynomial::Term> a = this->head;
       shared_ptr<Polynomial::Term> b = other.head;

       while(a != nullptr && b != nullptr)
       {
           for(a; a != nullptr; a->next)
           {
                for(b; b!=nullptr; b->next)
                {
                    if(a->exponent == b->exponent)
                    {
                        sum = a->coeff+b->coeff;
                        result = shared_ptr<Term> newTerm (new Term( sum, exp, head ));
                    }

                }
                return newTerm;
            }
       }
```

Comment: Advice - Overload `operator +=` first.  Then implement `+` in terms of `+=`

Comment: Advice 2 : `I have begun to write the definition to overload the addition operator`  Don't write code not knowing what the final outcome will be.  You'll wind up painting yourself into a corner.  Plan your design first.  You've got a triple nested loop just to implement addition of the two polynomials.  That doesn't sound right.

Comment: Also, why are you not using `std::list`?.  Makes the code far more easier and less error prone.

Comment: The logic is wrong in the `+` function; it returns after the first iteration of `a` . I guess you are asking for an algorithm to add together the two polynomials. You have the right idea in that you need to iterate them, but it will need to be some sort of splicing operation.

Comment: I think it is a design bug to have `next` inside a `Term` which you are managing via `shared_ptr`. It renders the `shared_ptr` pointless because if you have the same Term (exponent/coeff) in different polynomials then they have to use a different instance anyway because their Next will be different.  Instead the poly could store a `std::forward_list<shared_ptr<Term>>`.  However, it's likely that `sizeof(shared_ptr) > sizeof(Term)` so it seems to me that just `std::forward_list<Term>` is more appropriate here. Using shared_ptr complicates your code and I don't see the benefit at this stage.